# Is there a way to vary the needed function input?

Tags: r, function, arguments, vary

I have the following function:

```
my_fct <- 
  function(input1, input2, input3) {
    output <- df %>%
  filter(x = input1 | x = input2 | x = input3
  )
  }
```

with let's say `input1 = c(1:10), input2 = c(1:10), input3 = c(1:10)`

In some occassions, I only need one or two of the three inputs,
like

`output <- my_fct(3, 5)`

Unfortunately, my approach requires to insert exactly three arguments. Is there a way to create a function, in which the argument input can vary?

I really appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: You can assign each argument to NULL in the definition line (`function(x=NULL, y=NULL, z=NULL`), which means that if you call the function without one of the variables, the missing one is passed to the function as NULL. Then, you can use `if`/`else` calls in the body of the function (`if(is.null(z)...`) to deal with the variables that are present vs. absent.

Comment: Your function is a little confusing because it doesn’t output anything and contains (assuming) a data frame that is defined in the global environment. Is `x` a column in that df? Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @jpsmith minor correction, `output` is returned. The function returns the value of the last expression, and the `<-` assignment always "returns" the value assigned though invisibly. Correcting `=` to `==`, then `my_fct(1,2,3)` shows nothing but `(my_fct(1,2,3))` shows what is being returned.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the tip! I didn’t realize the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to demonstrate using this dataset:

```r
DAT <- head(mtcars)
names(DAT)[2] <- "x"
```

1. Do you mean `filter(x == input1 | ...)`? `x=input1` is unlikely to work as I'm inferring.
2. Functions should not be breaking scope to assume that an object is visible in the calling environment (`df` here). Doing it this way breaks reproducibility and can make troubleshooting more difficult. In this case, it can be more difficult since if `df` does not exist, the error will likely reference `function` or `closure` and not just say `object 'df`' not found`, which can be confusing if you aren't familiar with what's going on.

   For the examples below, I'll explicitly add `.data` as the first argument to work around this. (Making it the first argument means it'll play nicely with dplyr.) Similarly, I'll guard against `"x"` not being found in the data ... it might be useful to read https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for this, though a bit more work and out of scope for this answer.
3. We can use default values of `NULL`, perhaps

   ```r
   my_fct <- function(.data, input1 = NULL, input2 = NULL, input3 = NULL) {
     stopifnot("x" %in% names(.data))
     .data %>%
       filter(
         if (is.null(input1)) FALSE else x == input1 |
         if (is.null(input2)) FALSE else x == input2 |
         if (is.null(input3)) FALSE else x == input3
       )
   }
   my_fct(DAT)
   #  [1] mpg  x    disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
   # <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
   my_fct(DAT, 4)
   #             mpg x disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710 22.8 4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   my_fct(DAT, 4, 8)
   #                    mpg x disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710        22.8 4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
   ```

   (We can't use `is.null(input1) | x == input1` since both sides of `|` are always run, and `x == NULL` returns a 0-length vector instead of what we need.)
4. If `input*` are always going to be length-1 vectors, we can simplify it a little with

   ```r
   my_fct <- function(.data, input1 = NULL, input2 = NULL, input3 = NULL) {
     stopifnot("x" %in% names(.data))
     .data %>%
       filter(x %in% c(input1, input2, input3))
   }
   my_fct(DAT)
   #  [1] mpg  x    disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
   # <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
   my_fct(DAT, 4)
   #             mpg x disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710 22.8 4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   my_fct(DAT, 4, 8)
   #                    mpg x disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710        22.8 4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
   ```
5. If you are looking for something a bit more flexible (such as someday wanting `input4` as well, then perhaps

   ```r
   my_fct <- function(.data, ...) {
     stopifnot("x" %in% names(.data))
     dots <- list(...)
     if (!length(dots)) return(.data[0,])
     .data[rowSums(sapply(dots, function(z) .data$x == z)) > 0,]
   }
   my_fct(DAT)
   #  [1] mpg  x    disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
   # <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
   my_fct(DAT, 4)
   #             mpg x disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710 22.8 4  108 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   my_fct(DAT, 4, 8)
   #                    mpg x disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710        22.8 4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
   my_fct(DAT, 4, 11, 29, 394, 8)
   #                    mpg x disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
   # Datsun 710        22.8 4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
   # Hornet Sportabout 18.7 8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
   ```